# Gulp watcher - call functions for single file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-4

I have a function that I want to apply to only the changed file with gulp 4.0 watcher e.g. the current task would be:

```
gulp.watch([
    paths.sourceFolder + "/**/*.js",
    paths.sourceFolder + "/**/*.html",
    paths.sourceFolder + "/**/*.less",
    paths.lessFolder + "/**/*.less",
], {}

).on('change', gulp.series(lint));
```

This works, gives output and when it fails e.g. lint errors it continues to watch for more changes. However when I try to reformat this to run just on the single file no matter what I do it simply falls over on error and doesn't give task detail output in the console e.g.

```
gulp.watch([
    paths.sourceFolder + "/**/*.js",
    paths.sourceFolder + "/**/*.html",
    paths.sourceFolder + "/**/*.less",
    paths.lessFolder + "/**/*.less",
], {}).on('change', (path) => {
    lint(someDoneFunction, path)
});
```

How can I make this function run for a single file and retain the same output and error handling as using gulp.series()?

Answer (score 0):

Use your function in the watch callback instead of attaching it to the chokidar instance.

```
gulp.watch(
    [
        paths.sourceFolder + "/**/*.js",
        paths.sourceFolder + "/**/*.html",
        paths.sourceFolder + "/**/*.less",
        paths.lessFolder + "/**/*.less",
    ],
    gulp.series(lint, something, somethingElse)
);
```

According to the [latest watch documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/api/watch.md), when you access the chokidar instance directly, as you do when you use `on('change',...)`, you loose most of the task system integrations.

Comment: Problem is that doesn't pass any information about which individual file changed for the tasks to work on.